# Semantic way to check if variable is None

Tags: python

I have a variable `x` that I want to cast to int or return None if it is None.

Is there a shorthand way of doing the following:

```
if x:
    x = int(x)
```

Comment: You mean `x = x and int(x)`?

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that's a great solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
x = int(x) if x else None
```

or

```
x = int(x) if x is not None else None
```

Comment: This doesn't work with 0: you should test "x is not None"

Comment: you mean this `x = int(x) if x is not None else None`

Comment: you mean `int(x) if x else x` or `int(x) if x is not None else None`